# How do I round a number to a number of significant leading digits in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, integer, rounding

I would like to round a number to 2 leading digits, using pure JavaScript.
I want to give a rough idea of the number and its size, but I don't want to bother the listener with too many digits.

So 6832 should round to 6800, but 8773278475 should round to 8800000000, not 8773278400.

Answer (score 2):

This function gives me the right results for integers:

```
/**
 * @param {integer} num - The number to round
 * @param {integer} leadingDigits - How many significant digits at the start to keep
 * @returns {integer} rounded num
 */
function round(num, leadingDigits) {
  let precision = Math.pow(10, num.toString().length - leadingDigits);
  return Math.round(num / precision) * precision;
}

console.log(round(6832, 2));
console.log(round(8773278475, 2));
console.log(round(8, 2));
```

This returns, as expected:

```
6800
8800000000
8
```

---

But it fails for float, due to the `.toString().length` hack. If somebody has a better solution, please feel free to post it.

A good solution is short and easy to understand.